# ASP.NET MVC - Route.Config Default Start for different URLs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm new to MVC and I have a question concerning routing.
How can I configure routing so that a user always lands on my Default page?

I want it so that all controllers called by the URL should not be shown - they should be all be redirect to the Home View and then the user should be able to navigate from there. So If I have these Controllers: Home, Information and Tools, and I type in localhost/Information or localhost/Tools into the browser, the result should be the Index page of Home.

So, if the user types into his browser http://localhost/Information that he lands on http://localhost/Home. After landing on Home/Index they should then be able to navigate from links to the other Controllers and other Views.

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want all *undefined* controllers (that would normally get an error resolving the controller type) and all *undefined* action methods (that would also get an error) to reach the home page? And you don't want the controllers and actions that actually exist to exhibit this behavior? You can configure the route for `Information` to land on the home page (although you *should* do a 301 redirect for this) when typing `/Information`, but it is unclear if that is the only URL you want to do this.

Comment: @NightOwl888: No I want that all controllers which are defined and called by the URL should not be shown. They should be all redirect to the Home view and then the user should be able to navigate.
So If I have controllers for example Home, Information and Tools, and I type in localhost/Information or localhost/Tools in the browser. The result should be the Index page of Home.